# Translating (cropping) a GeoTIFF file to a specific extent but ending up with a different final extent

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal, gdalwarp, gdal-translate

I'm trying to crop a larger GeoTIFF file to a smaller extent.

[image]

The darker GeoTIFF file in the middle has the extent I want to reproject to. I've used the following command to do the translation:

```
gdal_translate -projwin 15.77934913 45.9207350629 16.24003059 45.712685371 large.tif large_translated.tif
```

However, after applying this I'm left with the following:

[image]

The green border is the reprojected GeoTIFF. As you can see it doesn't align with the smaller GeoTIFF and the resulting extent confirms that.

My target extent was:

```
15.7793491382775120,45.7126853719947803 : 16.2400305969196452,45.9207350629944528
```

The resulting extent is:

```
15.6999931171728377,45.7999983767051972 : 16.1999931826612027,45.9999983657800513
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I achieve the wanted behaviour through gdal?

Comment: What is your GDAL version?

Comment: @user30184 Version is `GDAL 3.7.0, released 2023/05/02`. I've resorted to using `gdalwarp` instead of `gdal_translate` as it seems to work as expected. Version in QGIS is `GDAL 3.7.2, released 2023/09/05` which exhibits the same behaviour.

Comment: Gdal_translate may also work at least partly as expected. The projwin selects pixels but it does not warp or rescale pixels. That is expected for gdal_translate.  Therefore exact cropping with -projwin requires that user gives the extent so that it matches with the pixel boundaries. But I would have expected that the cropped image would be bigger in all directions and cover the desired projwin completely.

Comment: Yea, I'm fairly certain that it works "as expected" but I was unaware that it doesn't warp or rescale pixels. Thanks!

Comment: Gdal_translate may rescale pixels if target size `-outsize` or target resolution `-tr` is defined.